# How to convert pandas DataFrame into bytes and vice versa?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to send a dataframe using socket programming.For that I need to know how to encode a dataframe into bytes at the client and then decode it into a dataframe at the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `cPickle` or `pickle` module.

First serialize the dataframe:

```
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4
>>> df_bytes = cPickle.dumps(df)
```

Send the contents of `df_bytes` somehow, then deserialize:

```
>>> df2 = cPickle.loads(df_bytes)
>>> df2
   A  B
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

---

These two modules does introduce potential security issues as they allow executing arbitrary code during deserialization. A better solution would be to write the dataframe into a json string:

```
df_string = df.to_json()
```

And recover it afterwards:

```
df_again = pandas.read_json(df_string)
```

Other formats such as `csv` are also available, the corresponding functions are `DataFrame.to_csv()` and `pandas.read_csv()`. See [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id12) and [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#input-output) for a complete list of related functions.

Comment: Could not find the package.Plus I read it is not secure.Any other suggestions?

Comment: These two modules are in the standard library. So no additional package is needed. Simply `import pickle` or `import cPickle` will do. I have edited the post to add methods converting to and from string formats, which should be  more secure.

Comment: Thanks Man. I tried with pickle.It is working. Security is not so much of an issue as of now.So going to use pickle for now. Will try the json later.